# Add Gesture to UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a customed overlay view for my UIImagePickerController.

I want to add an UITapGestureRecognizer in this overlay view in order to draw a circle and focus the camera. 
But once I added the gesture, my method is never called and I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
// Overlay view
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
// TapGesture
UITapGestureRecognizer *stabilisateurGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Stabiliser:)];
stabilisateurGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[overlay addGestureRecognizer:stabilisateurGesture];
// UIImagePickerController
pickerCamera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
pickerCamera.delegate = self;
pickerCamera.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
pickerCamera.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
pickerCamera.showsCameraControls = NO;
pickerCamera.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

And here the gesture method:

```
- (void)Stabiliser:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
     CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
     // Create circle
     UIView *cercleRouge = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(point.x-(86/2), point.y-(86/2), 86, 86)];
     cercleRouge.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
     cercleRouge.layer.borderWidth = 4;
     cercleRouge.layer.cornerRadius = cercleRouge.frame.size.height/2;
     [gesture.view addSubview:cercleRouge];
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried your code in a small separate view controller. It looks like it works. Did you try to add breakpoint in your "Stabiliser" method?

Comment: Really ? I did the same but that doesn't work for me... I put a NSLog in the method but it never appears.

I forgot to say I use `[self presentViewController:pickerCamera animated:YES completion:nil];` at the end, maybe the problem come from here ?